# Gegeben + {<Nominativ> oder <Akkusativ>}?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative, nominative

Which one is correct?

> Gegeben etwa der Term 1 des Typs *Int*, dann ist 1+1 ebenso vom Typ *Int*.
>
> Gegeben etwa den Term 1 des Typs *Int*, dann ist 1+1 ebenso vom Typ *Int*.
>
> Gegeben etwa der Term 1 des Typs *Int*, ist 1+1 ebenso vom Typ *Int*.
>
> Gegeben etwa den Term 1 des Typs *Int*, ist 1+1 ebenso vom Typ *Int*.

Which setences of the above are correct and which are not? Why? References to reputable sources are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

*Gegeben* is the past participle of *geben*, and used here like an adjective, so it doesn't rule any case.

The case of the substantive of the sentence is purely ruled by the verb here, which is "ist" - And this wants nominative.

> Gegeben ist der Term

just like

> Grün ist der Wald

(Actually, the sentence is *Zustandspassiv*, but I think the analogy to an adjective is easier to grasp)

Comment: @MdAyquassar your new examples are still wrong. You just omitted the word _dann_ in the part after the comma, but are still missing the verb _ist_ in the main clause before the comma.

Comment: @MdAyquassar I just wanted to point out that the additional _dann_ in your new examples doesn't change them regarding your question or tofro's answer. To be honest, I only know the _gegeben sei_ formulation, but I'm not a  mathematician. The sentence without _sei_ or _ist_ sounds odd to me.

Comment: @MdAyquassar The point is, without a "dann" or "so" the sentences 3 and 4 don't make any sense, even in a formal mathematical context where we tend to handle grammar a bit more loosely. These are all supposed to be "if-->then" statements that don't make a lot of sense without stating this.